# exposing an object to a user control via properties

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to expose a label in my page to a user control.  So I decided to create a public property in my user control, and then set that property in the page.

In my user control, I have this public property:

```
Public Property lblTestLabel As Label
```

then I do this:

```
lblTestLabel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("Display", "inline")
```

And in my page that includes the user control, I do this:

```
ucTestUserControl.lblTestLabel = lblRealLabel
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on the line where I try to set the CssStyle.  I know the object exists in the page, but I don't think that the object is being properly exposed to the user control.

Any idea on how to do this properly?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to control properties of controls that are on actual page using usercontrol? You can add attribute in page itself instead of passing label to usercontrol

Comment: good question. The user control contains a gridview...and I actually set a few attributes of controls in its RowCommand event. The controls that need attributes set exist on the page. -thanks

Comment: Can you create a readonly (string) property on your user-control...and try to read it out.  (Just to make sure that the control exists and is in scope where you're writing your code)

Comment: Where is the call to `.Add()`? Is it inside the property, in a Get or Set? Or is it a call inside the UserControl?

Comment: @ granadaCoder, I created a test string property in the uc and was able to set it in my page...so the test worked.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish as an end result? I don't think you are going about this the right way. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763876/wpf-frame-accessing-parent-page-controls) for a better approach.

Comment: @999cm999, you can't call methods on properties except the Get and Set methods, and only through assignment. Your call to .Add() isn't valid here.

Comment: @alldayremix My page uses a usercontrol that contains a gridview.  The gridview has a RowCommand event for a column of buttons.  When a button is pressed, it needs to update a label on the page.

Comment: So did you "draw" a label on your user-control?  Like, I would put a label on my user control......then I'd write a setter and getter property that would interact with the private member variable of the user-control label.

Comment: You're better off having the UserControl fire an event when the button is pressed, and having a corresponding event handler in your page that updates the label itself.

Comment: Public Property MyCoolLabelExposedAsAProperty() As Label
 Get
     Return Me.lblLastName
 End Get
 Set(ByVal value As Label)
      Me.lblLastName = value
 End Set
    End Property

Comment: I agree with alldayremix on popping an event and handling it.

Comment: @granadaCoder You still can't call .Add() on that label property. With that setup, you have to create a new label, call .Add() on it, and then set the property to that new label. You're better off creating a method on your page that the UserControl can call, that does the actual updating of the label. But again, that's not really the best design, it's too closely-coupled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call methods this way. A property isn't a variable, it is just a data element.

`lblTestLabel` isn't an instance of a Label. You need to define an underlying variable for the property to correspond to, and then call the Add() method on the variable, not the property itself.

```
Dim _lblTestLabel As Label
_lblTestLabel = New Label   ' This goes in your constructor, not here
Public Property lblTestLabel As Label
    Get          
        _lblTestLabel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("Display", "inline")
        return _lblTestLabel
    End Get
    Set (value As Label)
        _lblTestLabel = value
    End Set
End Property
```

That said, the statement `ucTestUserControl.lblTestLabel = lblRealLabel` overwrites the label underlying the property anyway, so your call to `.Add()` doesn't even matter.

This is all mostly irrelevant though, as the main issue here is that this is a *very bad* way to handle this kind of behavior. You should use events and event handlers here: have the UserControl fire an event, and have the page handle that event and update the label itself.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was after on my comment.  (How your property is exposing a private member variable, and that the class must be created in the constructor.  But yeah, I agree.  Move to an Event driven system.  Agreed it is too tightly coupled.